# What does 「まま」means in this context?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

Found it in Japanese song, what does it mean in this context and where can I use it?[image: ガラスのpalm tree]

Comment: It is more このまま https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E5%84%98

Comment: There are only a few possible words that could be spelled that way, and only one that remotely makes sense in context (and the only one seen in the collocation このまま). This is trivial to look up in a dictionary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Theoretically, 穴蛸のママ is not impossible :)